# Passing variable and php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, variables

I tried to search through the website but couldn't find a suitable answer for my problem or maybe I'm doing it the wrong way, but I'm making actually a Stock Exchange system for my final year project and I came through this problem.
First of all, I'm passing a variable through this:

```
<a href='#' id='<?php echo "". $row['id'] . ""?>' class="sell">
```

To the jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $(".sell").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var userid = element.attr("id");
    var info = 'id=' + userid;

    if (confirm("Do you really want to sell?")){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'sellstock.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: info,
        success: function(){
          alert('Sold, Please refresh to see your balance');
        }
      });

      $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(300, function({
        $(this).remove();
      });
    };

    return false;
  });
});
```

And the jquery calls the sellstock.php

```
<?php
include('session_user.php');

$stock_id = $_POST['id'];

$sql_getinfo = "SELECT *
                FROM transaction_user
                WHERE id='$stock_id'";

$row_info = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_getinfo, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$company_id = $row_info['company_id'];
$company_shares = $row_info['number_of_shares_bought'];
$company_price = $row_info['Price'];
$company_total = $row_info['Price_Value'];

$updatedbalance = $balance + $company_total;

$sql_stockinfo = "SELECT Shares_for_sale
                  FROM company_listed
                  WHERE id='$company_id'";

$row_stock = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_stockinfo, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$shares = $row_stock['Shares_for_sale'];


$updatedshares = $company_shares + $shares;

$updatebalance = "UPDATE balance SET current_balance = '$updatedbalance' where username ='$login_session'";
$resultbalance = mysqli_query($db , $updatebalance);

$updateshare = "UPDATE company_listed SET Shares_for_sale = '$updatedshares' where id= '$stock_id'";
$resultshare = mysqli_query($db, $updateshare);


$sqldelete = "DELETE FROM transaction_user WHERE id='$stock_id'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sqldelete);

header("location: Dashboardd.php");
?>
```

What I want to do is deleting the stock(from the given id), but before that, it should update the balance of the user and update the `shares_for_sale` of the company.

`$sqldelete = "DELETE FROM transaction_user WHERE id='$stock_id'";` `$result = mysqli_query($db, $sqldelete);`

The `$sqldelete` line is actually deleting the transaction, but I cant get any updates for the company and user balance. The update queries are working since when I hardcoded them, it was working but the issue is that with the `$stock_id`, its not working for the `$sql_getinfo` and since this is not working the `$sql_stockinfo` will not work and the `$updateshare` too.

The `$login_session` and `$balance` are called from `session_user.php` and working fine.

tables : https://scontent-mrs1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/16491661_10154975964354500_1753389524_o.jpg?oh=583059fbe0e2b8663acceedf0f1485c6&oe=58964E22

Comment: Could you beautify that jquery?

Comment: if you want i can send it all to you via mail lol, im in a deep struggle right now

Comment: It might also help to post the table structure... at least the relevant rows.  From reading, it appears that `$stock_id` is really more of a transaction_id, correct?

Comment: Yes do please share the transaction table. We need to see the fields and the data that it contains. One row is sufficient.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: [link]https://scontent-mrs1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/16491661_10154975964354500_1753389524_o.jpg?oh=583059fbe0e2b8663acceedf0f1485c6&oe=58964E22

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
$sql_getinfo = "SELECT *
            FROM transaction_user
            WHERE id='$stock_id'";
```

`$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql_getinfo);`
`$row_info = mysqli_fetch_array($);`

Answer (score 0):

### Points to be noted:

Its good practice to check the variable before using it in query

```
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
  $stock_id = $_POST['id'];
}
else {
 //Show error message or redirect to the homepage. whatever you prefer
}
```

No need to add extra quotes

```
<a href='#' id ='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>' class="sell">
```

Use the quotes carefully around the variables in queries

```
$sql_getinfo = "SELECT *
                FROM transaction_user
                WHERE id= ".$stock_id;

$sql_stockinfo = "SELECT Shares_for_sale
                  FROM company_listed
                  WHERE id= ".$company_id;

$updatebalance = "UPDATE balance SET current_balance = ".$updatedbalance." where username = '".$login_session."'";

$updateshare = "UPDATE company_listed SET Shares_for_sale = ".$updatedshares." where id= ".$stock_id;

$sqldelete = "DELETE FROM transaction_user WHERE id= ".$stock_id;
```

Comment: https://scontent-mrs1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/16491661_10154975964354500_1753389524_o.jpg?oh=583059fbe0e2b8663acceedf0f1485c6&oe=58964E22

Comment: No, still the same outcome, the transaction_user where the id was passed got deleted from the table, but no updates for balance and company_listed tables

Comment: ok. let me arrange your code in my local environment, then I can answer you more clearly